# magento - images not showing

Tags: magento, content-management-system, media

I added a custom field for all cms pages and enabled text editor and i display the value in a phtml file.
This is working fine,but the images not showing properly,it is not evaluated,it display like as below,

```
  <img style="float: left;" title="Incorrect method of de-coiling   " src="{{media url=" wysiwyg="" faqs="" 2-incorrect-method.jpg"}}"="" alt="Incorrect method of de-coiling   " width="230">
```

I display this content via the following code

```
 <?php echo nl2br($post['post_content']); // display content ?>
```

Please help me to evaluate this content properly,I am new in magento

Answer (score 0):

When adding images using wysiwyg editor button they will be relative to root/media/wysiwyg directory

```
img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/myfile.jpeg"}}"/>
```